# Conditional statements in MySQL where

Tags: mysql

It's late and I might be going about this completely wrong, but I'm trying to perform a very specific query.

I have a table called `content`.  Each piece of content has a type (ie. `news`, `events`, etc.).  I also have a `event_featured` boolean column that only applies to `event` items.  I'd like to pull ALL content except for events that are NOT featured.

So, the query would ignore `event_featured` altogether if the type isn't `events`, but it would only select events that have `event_featured` set to one.

In my mind, the plain English query sounds like this: "Select everything from `content` but exclude `type event` if `event_featured` equals 1"

I apologize if this is basic (again, it's late) or if my question doesn't make sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just converting your English statement into SQL:

```
select * from content where not (type='event' and event_featured=1)
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple like this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE type != 'event' AND event_featured = 1;
```

Comment: This statement is no output records with another types if `event_featured !=1`